# Мультипоточный парсер

Tags: php, python, golang

Как это обычно бывает. Есть магазины-поставщики, есть дилеры. И эти магазины-поставщики не могут дать никаких выгрузок, тем более актуальных. Единственный путь синхронизировать наличие товаров - парсить. Но когда количество товаров около 500 тысяч штук, то простой php-curl сдаётся. Может занять больше суток.
Поэтому, необходимо проходить по ссылкам многопоточно, ну и с прокси серверами, чтобы какой-нибудь cloudflare не заблокировал.

Есть ли какие-нибудь хорошие инструменты для такого парсинга. Интересует какая-то обёртка для упрощенной работы с многопоточностью и прокси серверами. Чтобы можно было ввести сколько один прокси сервер должен делать запросов в минуту, чтобы на вход пул урл только принимал и сам распределял их по потокам и т.д. Язык желательно один из: Python, PHP, GoLang. Может кто-то знает хороший инструмент?

**UPDATE:**

Оказывается php-curl-class не плохо справляется с задачей.Но всё равно, может, кто-то еще что-то знает.
https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class/blob/master/examples/multi_curl_proxies.php

Comment: Для этого есть [Gearman](http://gearman.org/download/#php) и его аналоги типа Quartz на .NET, правда повозиться придётся с настройкой проксей, но зато один раз.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

наверное, если нет АПИ и есть вероятность блокировки, то поставщик не сильно хочет, чтобы его продавали. во-вторых, не совсем понятна необходимость мультипоточности, если говорится, что парсинг может занять сутки. при таких сроках загрузка данных актуальна только роботами по расписанию, а не по запросу пользователя. а в случае с роботами, можно просто запускать их одновременно. причём если вынести исполнительные скрипты на разные сервера, то получится внутреннее распараллеливание. что в принципе реализуется и на php.

но если всё же требуется распараллеливание по запросу пользователя, то я бы посмотрел в сторону Node.js, как разделение непосредственно задачи на потоки, а ими уже бы запускал те же php-скрипты, потому что сам js не слишком приспособлен для программирования

Comment: При мультипоточности парсинг можно завершить за 30-60 минут. Просто наличие нужно обновлять два раза в сутки. Или хотя бы один раз. Вы предлагаете проверять наличие (делать запрос) при заходе на конкретный товар, да?

Comment: нет, я как раз за то, чтобы парсинг шел в фоновом режиме, не напрягая пользователя. причём постарался бы перераспределить нагрузку по времени так, чтобы основная масса работы ушла в наиболее тихие часы - на ночь, к примеру. и конечно более равномерно. чтобы не было: запустился, поработал полчаса и 6 часов простоя. пусть небольшими порциями выжирает каждые пару минут. но это всё конечно надо с учётом конкретной задачи

Comment: ну да, я так и хочу, только хочу чтобы это прошло более менее быстро. Но понял вас, не стоит слишком сильно нагружать. Можно запустить ночью и на 6ч будет не обломно

Answer (score 0):

если возможен python, то можно взять его multiprocessing и в несколько процессов запустить selenium

для проксирования можно натравить selenium на tor browser

у самого php с многопоточностью всё довольно печально